# How to pass variables through try_files?

Tags: nginx

Consider this configuration (given `/foo` doesn't exist):

```
server {
    set $x 1;

    location = / {
        set $x 0;
        try_files /foo @l;
    }

    location / {
        try_files /foo @l;
    }

    location @l {
        set_header X $x;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1000/;
    }
}
```

The response header `X` is always `1` even when I navigate to `/`. Why is this and how can I make variables propagate through `try_files`?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? This doesn't seem like the right way to go about...anything.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I want to enable FastCGI caching on only one specific URL. The only documentation I can find on it uses `if ($uri ~ ...) { set $x 0; }` but using `if` is discouraged. All configuration other than whether caching is enabled or not is the same.

Comment: Just use a `map` then.

Comment: Sounds like a typical [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, the right way to do what you want is by using the `fastcgi_no_cache` directive combined with a map. An example to show what it looks like :

```
map $uri $cache {
    default      "1";
    "~^/myuri"   "0";
}

server {

    ...

    location / {
        fastcgi_no_cache $cache;
        fastcgi_pass ...
    }

}
```